# sass error after upgrade from Angular 9 to 10

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

After the upgrade, I get the following error when running:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angu
lar/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\andne\Desktop\HomeOffice\ParesWebApp\Front-End\core\_navbar.scss:19:4: Can't resolve './images/default/logo.png' in 'C:\Users\andne\Desktop\HomeOffice\ParesWebApp\Front-End\src\assets\scss
'

  17 |     margin-right: 0;
  18 |     background-color: $navbar-brand-bg;
> 19 |     background-image: $navbar-brand-logo;
     |    ^
  20 |     background-repeat: no-repeat;
  21 |     background-position: center center;
```

For node-sass I have installed **4.13.1** and for sass-loader **11.0.1**

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does this help: Can't resolve './images/default/logo.png', have you moved the image or anything?

Comment: that was the mistake. Path was not correct. Wasted four hours of my life troubleshooting

Comment: no problem, don't feel bad it has happens to us all. But great that you got it working.